# How to sort in matlab using a custom comparator function

Tags: matlab, sorting, custom-sort

I am writing a program to find max possible number that can be formed from a vector of numbers in string format.

Like `A = ["3" "30" "33"]` should give `"33330"`. However a normal sort using `sort(A,'descend')` returns `"33303"`

Is there any way to use a comparator function in matlab to use as key while doing `sort(A)` ?

Something along the lines of `sort(A,key=compare_function)` where my compare function would compare two strings and return which is bigger as per the above logic (for example on inputs "30" and "3" it will form two strings "303" and "330", and return that "330" is bigger as per the logic)

Comment: So do you want to _sort_ the elements of `A`,  or return the _permutation_ that maximizes the concatenated number?

Comment: @LuisMendo for higher size of A , sorting in this custom way will give the required permutation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify this quicksort from the File Exchange to use your own custom compare function:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66704-quicksort?s_tid=srchtitle_quicksort_1